# continuous or analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry, holomorphic-functions

Let $P(x,t)=t^d+a_{d-1}(x)t^{d-1}+\ldots +a_0(x)$ with coefficients that are $\mathbb{C}$-analytic in the polydisc $D=\left\{x\in\mathbb{C}^m : \max |x_j|<r \right\}$. Assume that there exists a continuous function $\gamma :D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $P(t,\gamma(t))\equiv 0$.

Is $\gamma$ necessarily an analytic function?

Comment: yes, I should write $P(t,\gamma (t) )$ instead of $P(\gamma (t),t)$, I edited it.

Comment: You meant $x \in \mathbb{C}$ or $\gamma : D \to \mathbb{C}^m$. If $P$ is non-constant in each variable then it zeros are locally analytic curves ? Thus $\gamma$ should be analytic except at a few points